# Appropriate use of Monitor.Exit

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
void MethodA()
{
   Monitor.Enter(this);
   if(someCondition)
   {
       Monitor.Exit(this);
       // This point
       MethodB();
    }
    else
    {
        // Set some values only
 Monitor.Exit(this);
    }
}
```

If I have the above method which can be called in multi threads:

- Assume thread 1 is at `//This point`
- Another thread enters `Monitor.Enter` while thread 1 is still at `//This point`
- Will this stop `MethodB` from being executed? If yes, is there a way of getting `MethodB` to execute.

I need to release `MethodA` before executing `MethodB()` because I can't wait for `MethodB` to complete before releasing `MethodA`. Also, I cannot start `MethodB` in a new thread.

Comment: if exception happen lock will never be released, use it only in `try .. finally`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, someCondition is not passed as a parameter, I could only assume the someCondition could be changing at any time (possibly an instance variable to the class). So, I would write the code this way:

```
void MethodA()
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        bool conditionReached = false;

        Monitor.Enter(this);
        try
        {
            if (someCondition)
            {
                conditionReached = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(this);
        }

        if (conditionReached)
        {
            MethodB();
        }
    }
}
```

If not, than the previous answer with `condition` declared locally would suit you.

Comment: This is my situation! Thanks!!

Comment: In the original code, the lock is specifically acquired for the evaluation of someCondition, whereas this code will evaluate outside the lock.  This double-check approach avoids entering the lock if the condition is false, but the original code actually did something in the scope of the lock if the condition is false.  Finally, the 'double-check' approach is also potentially vulnerable to a rare race failure due to the lack of a memory barrier around the first evaluation of someCondition.  A lock imposes the memory barrier implicitly.

Comment: Dan is right. Aside from the fact that it behaves differently from the original it also has a subtle memory barrier problem.

Answer (score 8):

Setting aside the issue of using 'this' as a lock (bad practice, as it exposes the lock publically), this form is cleaner and safer (releases the lock if exception is thrown):

```
void MethodA()
{
   bool condition;
   lock(this)
   {
     condition = someCondition;
     if(!condition)
     {
        // Set some values only
     }
   }
   if (condition)
       MethodB();
}
```

To answer your specific question, both this code and your original code will execute MethodB, even if something else acquires the lock.